# My Query set is returning empty List even though there are users in the db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Below are listed my `Models`, `View`, and `Serializer` classes. I am making an admin dashboard where admin can create users, list them, and search a user by ID.

Users are being created successfully but the GET request for listing and searching returns an empty list even when there are users present in the Database.

**My Model Classes:**

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self,email,username,first_name,last_name, age, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have username")
        
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            age=age,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self,username,email,first_name,last_name,age,password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            age=age,)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email",max_length=60,unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined',auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login',auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField (max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    age = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='image',blank=True,null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','first_name','last_name','age']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + "," +self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**My Serializer Class:**

```
class UserSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','age','is_active']
        read_only_fields = ('email',)
        #fields = '__all__'
```

**My View Class:**

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    #authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]


    def list(self,request):
        
        queryset = self.get_queryset()  
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am sending a GET request to list all the users present but it is returning an empty list ([]).

There is no error but the return is an empty list.

However, I am creating users and they are being stored in Database.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the list() method?

Comment: did you migrate before creating your model?  Are you sure you have set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` in settings.py? I have tested from scratch with a few improvements on your code and everything seems alright.

Comment: @Niko should I just copy paste it in the settings?

Comment: @lucutzu33 it gives the same output (empty [ ] list)

Comment: If you migrated, please refer to [changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). Alternatively you can start fresh and [substitute-a-custom-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). Otherwise when trying to fetch the user model, Django will fetch from auth.user.